# (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle' - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow-lite, yolov4

As I detect my tflite file, the problem happened.

The command I wrote.

```
python detect.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-tf.tflite --size 416 --model yolov4 --image D:\yolov4\training\tensorflow-yolov4-tflite-master\data\rice.jpg --framework tflite --tiny true
```

And the wrong message:

```
cv2.rectangle(image, c1, c2, bbox_color, bbox_thick)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
>  - Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
```

Here is the related code.(core/utils.py)

```
fontScale = 0.5
    score = out_scores[0][i]
    class_ind = int(out_classes[0][i])
    bbox_color = colors[class_ind]
    bbox_thick = int(0.6 * (image_h + image_w) / 600)
    c1, c2 = (coor[1], coor[0]), (coor[3], coor[2])
    cv2.rectangle(image, c1, c2, bbox_color, bbox_thick)

    if show_label:
        bbox_mess = '%s: %.2f' % (classes[class_ind], score)
        t_size = cv2.getTextSize(bbox_mess, 0, fontScale, thickness=bbox_thick // 2)[0]
        c3 = (c1[0] + t_size[0], c1[1] - t_size[1] - 3)
        cv2.rectangle(image, c1, (np.float32(c3[0]), np.float32(c3[1])), bbox_color, -1) #filled

        cv2.putText(image, bbox_mess, (c1[0], np.float32(c1[1] - 2)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    fontScale, (0, 0, 0), bbox_thick // 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
return image
```

I have change it to

```
fontScale = 0.5
    score = out_scores[0][i]
    class_ind = int(out_classes[0][i])
    bbox_color = colors[class_ind]
    bbox_thick = int(0.6 * (image_h + image_w) / 600)
    c1, c2 = (int(coor[1]), int(coor[0])), (int(coor[3]), int(coor[2]))
    print(c1, c2, bbox_color, bbox_thick)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (int(coor[1]), int(coor[0])), (int(coor[3]), int(coor[2])), bbox_color, -1)

    if show_label:
        bbox_mess = '%s: %.2f' % (classes[class_ind], score)
        t_size = cv2.getTextSize(bbox_mess, 0, fontScale, thickness=bbox_thick // 2)[0]
        c3 = (c1[0] + t_size[0], c1[1] - t_size[1] - 3)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (int(coor[1]), int(coor[0])), (int(c3[0]), int(c3[1])), (255, 0, 0), -1) #filled

        cv2.putText(image, bbox_mess, (int(c1[0]), int(c1[1] - 2)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    fontScale, (0, 0, 0), bbox_thick // 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
return image
```

As it didn't got wrong, it still didn't show the image.

```
    [{'name': 'input_1', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 416, 416,   3]), 'shape_signature': array([ -1, 416, 416,   3]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
[{'name': 'Identity', 'index': 232, 'shape': array([   1, 2535,    4]), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1,  4]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'Identity_1', 'index': 211, 'shape': array([   1, 2535,    2]), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1,  2]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

[image: the last message]

Did anyone have any thought to solve it?
Thanks for your help!

Here is my files : https://github.com/piggychu0w0/food-image-detection

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing tuples with floats into the function's parameters as the points. Here is the error reproduced:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((600, 600), 'uint8')

c1 = 50.2, 12.4
c2 = 88.8, 40.8

cv2.rectangle(img, c1, c2, (255, 0, 0), -1)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    cv2.rectangle(img, c1, c2, (255, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
>  - Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
```

And to fix it, simply use the `int()` wrapper around the coordinates:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((600, 600), 'uint8')

c1 = 50.2, 12.4
c2 = 88.8, 40.8

cv2.rectangle(img, (int(c1[0]), int(c1[1])), (int(c2[0]), int(c2[1])), (255, 0, 0), -1)
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it still wrong. I add the wrong above.

Comment: cv2.rectangle(image, c1, (np.float32(c3[0]), np.float32(c3[1])), bbox_color, -1) #filled
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'

Comment: It has the new mistake.

Comment: @CYH Try `cv2.rectangle(img, (int(c1[0]), int(c1[1])), (int(c2[0]), int(c2[1])), (255, 0, 0), -1)`

Comment: Still having the same mistake.

cv2.rectangle(image, c1, (np.float32(c3[0]), np.float32(c3[1])), bbox_color, -1) #filled

Comment: @CYH But you have `(np.float32(c3[0]), np.float32(c3[1]))`...

Comment: So I need to change it to cv2.rectangle(image, int(c1), (int(c3[0]), int(c3[1])), bbox_color, -1) #filled.
Like this?

Comment: It finally have not appear wrong.
But it still can't show the image.
This is the last it process.
What does it means??

Comment: I add the message at the bottom of the post. Do you have any experience about this?? @Ann Zen

Comment: If `c1` is a tuple, you can't do `int(c1)`; you'll need to unpack it.

Answer (score 3):

Just try the below changes it's works for me.

```
fontScale = 0.5
    score = out_scores[i]
    class_ind = int(out_classes[i])
    bbox_color = colors[class_ind]
    bbox_thick = int(0.6 * (image_h + image_w) / 600)
    c1, c2 = (coor[0], coor[1]), (coor[2], coor[3])
    print(c1, c2, bbox_color, bbox_thick)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (int(c1[0]), int(c1[1])), (int(c2[0]), int(c2[1])), bbox_color, bbox_thick)

    if show_label:
        bbox_mess = '%s: %.2f' % (classes[class_ind], score)
        t_size = cv2.getTextSize(bbox_mess, 0, fontScale, thickness=bbox_thick // 2)[0]
        c3 = (c1[0] + t_size[0], c1[1] - t_size[1] - 3)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (int(c1[0]), int(c1[1])), (int(c3[0]), int(c3[1])), (255, 0, 0), -1) #filled

        cv2.putText(image, bbox_mess, (int(c1[0]), int(c1[1] - 2)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    fontScale, (0, 0, 0), bbox_thick // 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
return image
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n_lines = len(bbox)
    for i in range(n_lines):
        # draw all lines
        point1 = tuple(bbox[i][0])
        point2 = tuple(bbox[(i+1) % n_lines][0])
        cv2.line(img, point1, point2, (255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
```

Comment: Can you please check your indentation?

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `cv2.pointPolygonTest()` on the pt. parameters which test if a point is inside a polygon.

Recent version of opencv expect consistent value type for parameters. In my case, contour was in np.uint8.

So I had to convert my `[x_value,y_value]` to a uint8 np.array using

```
point = np.array([x_value,y_value]).astype(np.uint8)
```