# OpenCV Error: bad argument, Overload resolution failed, Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type

Tags: python, opencv

I'm doing a simple project to detect QR codes and draw bounding boxes from a webcam capture.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys 
import time
#
# Sanity Check
print("QR Scanner initialized.")


# Utility function to get a video frame from webcam.
# @param: cap is a cv2.videoCapture object.
def captureFrame(cap):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Capture failed.")
    return frame

# Utility function to draw bounding box on frame.
def display(img, bbox):
    n = len(bbox)
    
    for j in range(n):
        cv2.line(img, 
                 tuple(bbox[j][0]), 
                 tuple(bbox[ (j+1) % n][0]), 
                 (255,0,0), 
                 3)
        cv2.imshow("Video", img)
    
# Function to detect QR code in an input image
def qrDetect(inputImage):
    # Create a qrCodeDetector Object.
    qrDecoder = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

    # Look for a qr code.    
    t = time.time()
    
    data, bbox, rectifiedImage = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(inputImage)
    print("Time Taken for Detect and Decode : {:.3f} seconds.".format(time.time() - t))
    
    # Print output if applicable.
    if len(data) > 0:
        print("Decoded Data : {}".format(data))
        return 1, inputImage, bbox
    else:
        print("QR Code not detected")
        return 0, inputImage, 0


# Main function.  
def main():
    print("I'm alive!")
    
    # Stream webcam frames until 'q' is pressed.
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) 
    while True:
        frame = captureFrame(cap)
        ret, img, bbox = qrDetect(frame)
        
        if ret:
            display(img, bbox)
        else:
            cv2.imshow("Video", img)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'line'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

From what I've read from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874634/cv2-error-opencv4-5-3-error-bad-argument-overload-resolution-failed-in-cv), the tuples cv2.line is being passed have to be comprised of ints.

I've tried:

1. iterating through bbox and casting each value as ints

```
for j in range(n):
    cv2.line(img, 
             tuple(int(bbox[j][0])), 
             tuple(int(bbox[ (j+1) % n][0])), 
             (255,0,0), 
             3)
```

2. using .astype(int)

```
bbox = bbox.astype(int)
for j in range(n):
    cv2.line(img, 
             tuple(bbox[j][0]), 
             tuple(bbox[ (j+1) % n][0]), 
             (255,0,0), 
             3)
```

Edit: the contents of bbox (four corners of a single bounding box) are as follows:

```
[[[134.13043 150.     ]
  [362.3125  150.     ]
  [360.64886 362.94632]
  [143.58028 367.34634]]]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: cv2.line wants arguments 1 and 2 to be tuples containing the x and y coordinates of the start and end points of the line. Even if the cast is removed, the same error occurs.

Comment: thanks for getting me to investigate this again. OpenCV learns new things all the time and this is one such instance. practical advice: update your version of OpenCV.

Comment: since you appear new (in terms of activity) on this site, please take the [tour]. if my answer has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

OpenCV wants a tuple of **integers** there, while you give it a tuple of numpy floats.

Yes, the error message doesn't clearly say that it wants integers.

This error happens with many drawing functions of OpenCV. The usual ones are `cv.line`, `cv.rectangle`, `cv.circle`, ...

**The fix:** convert the array to integer with `the_array.astype(int)`, i.e. say something like:

```py
cv.line(..., pt1=bbox[j][0].astype(int), ...)
```

You could also add proper rounding and say `the_array.round().astype(int)`

That seems to work on *current* OpenCV (tested with 4.5.4) because its bindings generation seems to have learned a few new tricks. **Previously**, one had to do a few more things:

- give it an actual tuple, not just a numpy array
- make sure the integers are python ints, not numpy ints

Like so:

```py
(x,y) = bbox[j][0]
cv.line(..., pt1=((int(x), int(y)), ...)
```