# Can't parse 'src'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type (OpenCV- .train)

Tags: python, opencv

I can't figure out why my snippet of code keeps failing, maybe some of you could help.

```
import re
import cv2 as cv
import os 
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image



import pickle 
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Faces")


face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\swhit\Documents\OPENCVTests\Basic-Augmented-reality-course-opencv-master\GENERATE_MARKERS\Cascades\data\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
recognizer = cv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()


current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels = []
x_train = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            #print(label, path)
            if label in label_ids:
                pass
            else:
                label_ids[label] = current_id
                current_id += 1
            id_ = label_ids[label]


            y_labels.append(label) # Some number
            x_train.append(path) # Verify this, turn into NUMPY, GRAY
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L") # Grayscale
            image_array = np.array(pil_image, "uint8")
            #print(image_array)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                x_train.append(roi)
                y_labels.append(id_)

#print(y_labels)
#print(x_train)

with open("labels.pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)

recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save("trainer.yml")
```

In specific it's the `recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))` part. I get this error code

```
OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'train'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'src'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'src'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle' - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921192/5bad-argument-in-function-rectangle-cant-parse-pt1-sequence-item-wit)

Comment: it requires a different `dtype`.