# Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type error using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
    
src = cv2.imread("cup.webp")
dst = src.copy()
    
gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 5, blockSize=3, useHarrisDetector=True, k=0.03)
    
for i in corners:
    cv2.circle(dst, tuple(i[0]), 3, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
cv2.imshow("dst", dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I find the "Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type error" when I run the code.

here is the image:

```
https://076923.github.io/assets/posts/Python/OpenCV/lecture-23/1.webp
```

Comment: please share the image that you are using. So we can help you out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle' - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921192/5bad-argument-in-function-rectangle-cant-parse-pt1-sequence-item-wit)

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask]

Comment: You cannot do this tuple(i[0]). You need coordinates.

Comment: Does this help? cv2.circle(frame, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), 2, (0, 0, 255), -1)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I solved this problem by doing the below.

Comment: for i in range(corners.shape[0]):
    pt = (int(corners[i, 0, 0]), int(corners[i, 0, 1]))
    cv2.circle(dst, pt, 3, (0, 0, 255), 2)