# iris localization using hough transform

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, google-colaboratory, hough-transform

This code has been successful for localizing and cropping the iris:

[image]

```
# circles = cv2.HoughCircles(canny,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10000,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=50,maxRadius=100)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(canny,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10000,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=1000)

height,width = gray.shape
r = 0
mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)
for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(bgr,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),3)
    cv2.circle(mask,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,255),thickness=-1)
    blank_image = bgr[:int(i[1]),:int(i[1])]

    masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=mask)
    _,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0][0])
    crop = masked_data[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    r = i[2]
    crop_dim =cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

plt.imshow(bgr)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(crop_dim)
plt.savefig('Hough Transform')
plt.show()
```

but after i tried it a month later and got the result like this

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-74f81f85c0bc> in <module>()
      6 mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)
      7 for i in circles[0,:]:
----> 8     cv2.circle(bgr,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),3)
      9     cv2.circle(mask,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,255),thickness=-1)
     10     blank_image = bgr[:int(i[1]),:int(i[1])]

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'circle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

Comment: what's the value of i?

Comment: probably a floating point number. question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921192/5bad-argument-in-function-rectangle-cant-parse-pt1-sequence-item-wit

Comment: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qDdH4Z0R7GPB4EpxBh8i1U_xqQnqogq5?usp=sharing) I don't know where the problem is, because it worked before

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: Does the code work with the first line instead of the second ?

Comment: right, it was a month before and when I tried run all and the result was like that @YvesDaoust

Comment: So isn't it obvious that the cause is `minRadius` ?

Comment: where is the min radius? in the second? there is also a min radius in the first one but the image is cut off @YvesDaoust

Comment: Ooops, also `maxRadius`.

Comment: it's not a problem, I've tried it @YvesDaoust

Comment: Can you post original eye, please?

Comment: its really a duplicate but the context is different, i don't understand what i should change, can you help me? @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: you need to understand what "types" are. the **solution** (multiple even!) _is_ given in the question I linked.

Comment: i have been trying it and it works! thankyou so much @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: god bless u @ChristophRackwitz